# How to use Qt beginInsertRows correctly

Tags: c++, qt, listview, model-view-controller, model

I have my custom `ItemModel` and `ItemDelegate`:

```cpp
class ItemModel : public QAbstractListModel {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  // return items_.size();
  int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;

  // return items_[index.row()];
  QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;

  void Insert(const QVector<QString> &data);
private:
  QVector<QString> items_;
};

void ItemModel::Insert(const QVector<QString> &data) {
  // my question is the 'first' and 'last' args of beginInsertRows
  beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), 0, 0);
  items_.insert(items_.begin(), data.begin(), begin.end());
  endInsertRows();
}
```

From [Qt Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertRows), it say `beginInsertRows` has three args:

> void QAbstractItemModel::beginInsertRows(const QModelIndex &parent, int first, int last)
>
> Begins a row insertion operation.
>   When reimplementing insertRows() in a subclass, you must call this function before inserting data into the model's underlying data store.
>   The parent index corresponds to the parent into which the new rows are inserted; first and last are the row numbers that the new rows will have after they have been inserted.

I am not sure how to pass `last` and `first`, in my `ItemModel::Insert`, whatever the size of the inserted data is 0 or 10 or other count, I pass `first = 0` and `last = 0`, the view work correctly. When I insert 10 items, and pass `first = 0` and `last = 9`, the view work correctly too. It confuse me.

```cpp
void ItemModel::Insert() {
  beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), 0, 0);
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    items_.push_back(QString::number(i);
  }
  endInsertRows();
}

// or
void ItemModel::Insert() {
  beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), 0, 9);
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    items_.push_back(QString::number(i));
  }
  endInsertRows();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`0, 0` is not correct because "*first* and *last* are the row numbers that the new rows **will have after** they have been inserted." The view may still look correct using these parameters but there might be problems from it you haven't seen yet.

`0, 9` is correct, but only the first time `Insert()` is called, because you are adding the new numbers to the end. You need to add `items_.size()` to both parameters. I.e.:

```
  beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), items_.size(), items_.size() + 9);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the doc you highlighted says, you need to call those two functions when you reimplement  the virtual function  `QAbstractItemModel::insertRows`

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#insertRows

Which is obviously not what you are doing in your ItemModel::Insert function.

Comment: But, quoting from your very link, "you can reimplement [insertRows] if you want to support insertions. **Alternatively**, you can provide **your own API** for altering the data. **In either case**, you will need to call `beginInsertRows()` and `endInsertRows()` to notify other components that the model has changed."